# SSL response getting split over two callbacks

Tags: ssl, erlang, websocket, cowboy

I'm developing a client-server application and have been tasked with adding support for running over websockets. I'm using Cowboy on the server side, and have been working on an Erlang websocket client for testing.

Things are supposed to go like:

1. client opens socket connection and starts http handshake
2. server completes http handshake
3. client sends message to server and server sends reply
4. client handles reply
5. repeat 3 & 4

The client module implements

```
handle_info({Transport, Socket, Data}, StateName, State) ->
    ... do stuff with data ...
```

which is called by the underlying transport (gen_tcp or ssl) when data shows up.

Everything works fine when I configure the client and server to use `gen_tcp`. When I instead use `ssl`, the websocket handshake completes, but in step 4, I'm getting a callback to `handle_info` that contains only the first byte of data returned from the server. A subsequent callback will contain the remainder of the response.

I'm really confused by this behaviour given that the same code with gen_tcp swapped in works fine, and we have two other transports built using `ssl` (but not websockets or cowboy) that similarly do not exhibit this behaviour.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing data to get split this way? I'd prefer not to have to write handling for this if I don't need to.

**Update:** Just for kicks, I modified the client so that it will wait for two callbacks to occur and will concatenate the data from both before trying to parse it. This solves the problem, but still leaves me baffled.

I did notice a couple things though:

- the first set of two callbacks always contains exactly one byte
- that byte is always 130 (0x82)

No idea if that's relevant or not.

Comment: Since @EJP mentionned you can't rely on tcp boundaries the way you do, solving it by waiting for *exactly* two callbacks to occur may work for now, but may break in some unexpected cases or just with a future release of Erlang. You should rather accumulate the binary parts until you have effectively everything you need to at least do part of the work. What's garanteed is that on the same socket, different messages won't interleave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no message boundaries in TCP. You don't have any right to rely on the behaviour you are expecting. The transport can give you data in whatever pieces it likes, as long as it provides it all, intact, in the correct order. TCP provides you with a byte stream, and most SSL libraries ditto (although at a lower level there are indeed SSL record messages).

Comment: This has always been my understanding as well, yet we've got three  implementations that pre-date my involvement (including two that are using ssl) that, for better or worse, haven't had any issues relying on this behaviour in production. If this were an intermittent problem, I'd maybe buy that we've just been lucky, but the fact that this one implementation is consistently getting one byte returned first seems like there must be a more specific issue.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not trying to dispute the nature of TCP, or claiming that those other implementations are "correct". I'm just curious why they consistently behave as if they were, while this new implementation is consistently different.

Comment: @JohnPrice It is allowed to be consistently different, by the nature of TCP.